# 403 Forbidden Access phpMyAdmin with correct config with personal computer IP

Tags: phpmyadmin, ip, config

I am trying to setup a MySQL database and phpMyAdmin on my VPS server. The MySQL database launches fine and so does the website part of phpMyAdmin. But when I go to (my VPS ip here)/phpmyadmin it says 403 Forbidden Access - You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server. My configuration has my computer IP in all the 4 spaces. Here is my config (my actualy is replaced with a placeholder for you viewing):

```
# phpMyAdmin - Web based MySQL browser written in php
# 
# Allows only localhost by default
#
# But allowing phpMyAdmin to anyone other than localhost should be considered
# dangerous unless properly secured by SSL

Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip (MY COMPUTER IP HERE)
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from (MY COMPUTER IP HERE)
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip (MY COMPUTER IP HERE)
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from (MY COMPUTER IP HERE)
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

# This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
# filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
#
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
#        SecRuleInheritance Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions here, but you are aliasing Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin as the directory in your config file, but when you make your "allow" statement you are giving permission to access the /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/ directory beneath it. If you are attempting to connect to /phpMyAdmin then your allow rule would not cover the parent directory. You might also want to look for anything in the .htaccess that would prevent the connection.